# How to stop/kill deferred processes which are in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-deferred, deferred

I have a code block where I will process a

```
function processBlocks(){
   var data = [1,2,3,4]; // some array
   var processItemsDeferred = [];
   for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
       processItemsDeferred.push(processItem(data[i]));
   } 
   $.when.apply($, processItemsDeferred).then(everythingDone); 
 }
function processItem(data) {
   var dfd = $.Deferred();
   console.log('called processItem');
   setTimeout(function() { dfd.resolve() }, 2000); 

  return dfd.promise();
} 
function everythingDone(){
 console.log('processed all items');
} 
function mainOne() {

  processBlock();

}
```

The mainOne() function can be called any number of times immediately. But once one processBlock() function is called, the deferred process of the old one should be killed and the new one should start.

Is there any way to do? Currently, the old deferred is not getting killed and the other one will start and it continues.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve (rather than the technical issue you think you need to resolve)?

Comment: In you example, in case a setTimeout is already running when processBlock is called the setTimeout will be stopped?